# Play and pause html5 video at certain point

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to start the video after class `mySlides` are replaced and it's actually the video element that's displayed. Once the video is done I would like to pause but the sound isn't playing still. Basically what its doing now is displaying the first `div` but, adding the sound from the video behind it. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  var vid = document.getElementById("vid");

  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  vid.pause();
  vid.currentTime = 0;
  vid.play();
  setTimeout(showSlides, 36000); // Change image every minute
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none
}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}
```

```html
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="8000">

<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <iframe src="http://192.168.4.68" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; 
    height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;"></iframe>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <video id="vid" src="/static/PUT_MEETING_08-20_WSUBS.webm"></video>
  </div>
</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you reloading the page after 8000 seconds?

Comment: I tried to make a snippet. It does not actual run anything

Comment: If you only need audio I would suggest looking into the [`audio` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Video_and_audio_APIs).

Comment: Basically the first div is an iframe for slides that I pull from another web application, so I reload the page to pull in new slides after 8000 seconds @mplungjan

Comment: I would like the slide show to play first (first .mySlides this has no audio only pictures). then after that the next div of (.mySlides) contains a video. This video should only start when its actually its turn to be displayed. Right now its playing the video behind the slides and you can hear the audio.

Comment: If the iframe data is from the same origin as the page, I suggest strongly ajax instead of reloading the complete page

Comment: As for your question, please [Research your title](https://www.google.com/search?q=html5+video+pause+at+time+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @mplungjan I figured it out - see below for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I added this in and it works like a charm! Might be messy but, it gets the job done. Thanks for the help everyone!

```
if(String(slides[slideIndex-1].children.item(0).outerHTML).includes("video")) {

  var vid = document.getElementById("vid");
  vid.play();
} 
else 
{
  var vid = document.getElementById("vid");

  vid.pause();
}
```